# Project manager + mercurial

Tags: mercurial, project-management, hosting, dvcs

I have started working on my projects with a team, it is a small team (only 3) but we are on different places.

I'm searching for a tool that provides the following:

1. mercurial hosting
2. project management (to do lists, milestones ... etc something like Project Pier)
3. if it is free this would be great! if not i can pay up to $30 - $50 / month

We all use different IDEs,  eclipse and dreamweaver, and it would take sometime so we can all decide one IDE to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me add [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) to the list of tools:

1. Mercurial and Git hosting — that's their core competence.
2. They have a simple bug tracker that might or might not be enough. I suspect this will be the least good fit: it's a bug tracker, not a project management tool as such.
3. They have free private repositories for up to 5 collaborators. This makes them a good choice for small companies or small teams like yours.

Using Bitbucket will of course require that you can put your data in the cloud. Sometimes regulations prohibit this. On the other hand, you avoid having to install and configure your own software and servers.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest looking at [Redmine](http://redmine.org)

It can be setup as a project management system with issue tracking, roadmaps/milestones and lots of other great features. It is free and runs on top of a ruby-on-rails platform. I run my own server on an Ubuntu server box with Apache and have it setup to host Mercurial repositories. I have some basic setup instructions [here](https://www.evernote.com/pub/qtzar/redmineadvanced) that I put together while I was doing my install and there are lots of other instructions and how-tos on the redmine website.

If your looking for an externally hosted solution then I'd suggest taking a look at [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/). They offer public and private repositories and are fairly cost effective with a 5 user account with unlimited private repositories for free.

Answer (score 0):

Redmine is good suggestion, but, maybe, [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/plans) (as full-featured PM solution) will not be bad choice also.

For your team-size and budget limits you can use any plan from Starter-Group range or even [Assembla Portfolio](http://portfolio.assembla.com/)